# Animation performance with MKOverlayView ideas.

Tags: ios, animation, mapkit, overlay

I'm currently loading 7 Overlays with requested images, then after adding all the overlays to the map view, I cycle through through the overlayviews hiding all, except the current animation index. While this works to animate I can still each tile being drawn every single time, causing a very in-smooth animation. I will post code when I get bak to my laptop, but I was just curious if anyone, had any ideas. I would like to not use a sub UIView/UIImageView in the overlayview.